# SIGABRTCrash in xamarin_initialize iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm developing an app in Xamarin iOS and Android.
In a few case the iOS version (not android) report trough bug report system this problem:

> Thread 0SIGABRTCrash in xamarin_initialize
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib **pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 libsystem_c.dylib abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 140 2 TouristApp
>   xamarin_initialize (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (runtime.m:938) 3 TouristApp mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (mini-exceptions.c:2786) 4
>   TouristApp mono_handle_exception_internal (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (mini-exceptions.c:1727) 5
>   TouristApp mono_handle_exception (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   + 40 6 TouristApp handle_signal_exception (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (exceptions-arm64.c:525) 7
>   TouristApp
>   TouristApp_TouristApp_DettaglioPunti_UpdateDescriptionAudio_bool (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 76 8 TouristApp
>   TouristApp_TouristApp_DettaglioPunti__UpdateDescriptionAudioc__AnonStorey3__UpdateDescriptionAudioc__AnonStorey4__m__0
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 452 9 TouristApp Apply (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (NSAction.cs:57) 10 TouristApp
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 244 11 TouristApp
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mini-runtime.c:2564) 12 TouristApp mono_runtime_invoke (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (object.c:2897) 13 TouristApp
>   native_to_managed_trampoline_1() (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   + 208 14 TouristApp -[__MonoMac_NSActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 60 15
>   Foundation __NSThreadPerformPerform (in Foundation) + 340 16
>   CoreFoundation
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** (in CoreFoundation) + 24 17 CoreFoundation **CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in
>   CoreFoundation) + 540 18 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in
>   CoreFoundation) + 724 19 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in
>   CoreFoundation) + 384 20 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal (in
>   GraphicsServices) + 180 21 UIKit UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 204 22
>   TouristApp
>   (wrapper_managed-to-native)_UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 324 23 TouristApp Main (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (UIApplication.cs:63) 24 TouristApp
>   TouristApp_TouristApp_Application_Main_string** (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 56 25 TouristApp
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 244 26 TouristApp
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mini-runtime.c:2564) 27 TouristApp mono_runtime_invoke (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (object.c:2897) 28 TouristApp
>   mono_runtime_exec_main (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (object.c:4221) 29 TouristApp xamarin_main (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (monotouch-main.m:454) 30 TouristApp
>   main (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 96 31 libdyld.dylib start
>   (in libdyld.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 1
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib kevent_qos (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1
>   libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_source_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib) + 0
>
> Thread 2
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp thread_func (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:106) 2 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 3 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 3
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib semaphore_wait_trap (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 2 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 3 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 4
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp
>   wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (wait.c:187) 3 TouristApp mono_wait_uninterrupted (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:1518) 4 TouristApp
>   ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:1652) 5 TouristApp
>   wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal_System_Threading_WaitHandle_intptr_int_bool
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 128 6 TouristApp WaitOne (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (WaitHandle.cs:375) 7 TouristApp
>   WaitOne (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (WaitHandle.cs:388) 8
>   TouristApp SchedulerThread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (Timer.cs:395) 9 TouristApp ThreadStart_Context (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (thread.cs:72) 10 TouristApp
>   RunInternal (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (executioncontext.cs:957) 11 TouristApp Run (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (executioncontext.cs:893) 12
>   TouristApp ThreadStart (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (thread.cs:109) 13 TouristApp
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 244 14 TouristApp
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mini-runtime.c:2564) 15 TouristApp mono_runtime_invoke (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (object.c:2897) 16 TouristApp
>   start_wrapper (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:740) 17
>   TouristApp inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 18 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 19 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 20 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 5
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 6
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
>   1 CoreFoundation **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (in CoreFoundation) + 196
>   2 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1032 3
>   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384 4
>   CFNetwork +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] (in CFNetwork)
>   + 412 5 Foundation __NSThread__start** (in Foundation) + 1000 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) +
>   156 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 7
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib select$DARWIN_EXTSN (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 2 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 3 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 8
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp worker_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 3 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 9
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp worker_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 3 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 10
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 11
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 12
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
>   1 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (in CoreFoundation) + 196
>   2 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1032 3
>   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384 4
>   GeoServices _runNetworkThread (in GeoServices) + 428 5
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) +
>   156 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 13
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp worker_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 3 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 14
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 15
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 16
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp mono_thread_info_sleep (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (mono-os-mutex.h:135) 2 TouristApp
>   monitor_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (threadpool-ms.c:887) 3 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 4 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 17
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp worker_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 3 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 18
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 TouristApp worker_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-os-mutex.h:134) 2 TouristApp start_wrapper (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:717) 3 TouristApp
>   inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 19
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
>   1 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (in CoreFoundation) + 196
>   2 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1032 3
>   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384 4
>   WebCore RunWebThread() (in WebCore) + 456 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
>   7 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) +
>   4
>
> Thread 20
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 libc++.1.dylib std::__1::condition_variable::wait() (in
>   libc++.dylib) + 56 2 JavaScriptCore JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase()
>   (in JavaScriptCore) + 144 3 JavaScriptCore
>   JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() (in JavaScriptCore) + 84 4
>   JavaScriptCore WTF::threadEntryPoint() (in JavaScriptCore) + 212 5
>   JavaScriptCore WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() (in JavaScriptCore) + 24 6
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) +
>   156 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 21
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg_trap (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
>   1 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort (in CoreFoundation) + 196
>   2 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1032 3
>   CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384 4
>   libAVFAudio.dylib GenericRunLoopThread::Entry() (in libAVFAudio.dylib)
>   + 164 5 libAVFAudio.dylib CAPThread::Entry() (in libAVFAudio.dylib) + 84 6 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 7 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 8 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 22
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib semaphore_wait_trap (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 MediaToolbox fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread
>   (in MediaToolbox) + 1948 2 CoreMedia figThreadMain (in CoreMedia) +
>   272 3 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 5 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 23
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __workq_kernreturn (in
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
>   (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
>
> Thread 24
>
> 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib __psynch_cvwait (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) +
>   8 1 Foundation -[NSCondition wait] (in Foundation) + 240 2 Foundation
>   -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] (in
>   Foundation) + 792 3 Foundation -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions)
>   performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] (in Foundation)
>   + 144 4 TouristApp (wrapper_managed-to-native)_ObjCRuntime.Messaging:objc_msgSend (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 140 5 TouristApp
>   Foundation.NSObject:InvokeOnMainThread (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (NSObject2.cs:556) 6 TouristApp
>   TouristApp_TouristApp_DettaglioPunti__UpdateDescriptionAudioc__AnonStorey3__m__2 (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 236 7 TouristApp
>   m__0 (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (NSObject.g.cs:52) 8 TouristApp ThreadStart_Context (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (thread.cs:72) 9 TouristApp
>   RunInternal (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (executioncontext.cs:957) 10 TouristApp Run (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (executioncontext.cs:893) 11
>   TouristApp ThreadStart (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (thread.cs:87) 12 TouristApp
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) + 244 13 TouristApp
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mini-runtime.c:2564) 14 TouristApp mono_runtime_invoke (in
>   1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (object.c:2897) 15 TouristApp
>   start_wrapper (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a) (threads.c:740) 16
>   TouristApp inner_start_thread (in 1a944b2b614036bbba6b93191b43cf7a)
>   (mono-threads-posix.c:92) 17 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body (in
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156 18 libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0 19 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4

I don't understand if this is a problem of Mono/Xamarin or can be my code.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
As request in the comment this is the code of Main

```
public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Xamarin.Insights.Initialize ("xxxxxxxxx"); //id of the app on insight
            UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
```

And this is my AppDelegate

```
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations

        public override UIWindow Window {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("TouristAppStoryBoard", null);
        public static UIViewController initialViewController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {

            Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            initialViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController ();
            Window.RootViewController = initialViewController;

            var navController = Window.RootViewController as UINavigationController;
            navController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = ViewUtility.GetAttributesForTitleNavigationBar ();

            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnResignActivation (UIApplication application)
        {
        }

        public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
        {

            LocationManager.GetIstance ().StopLocationUpdates ();
            var taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask( () => {});
            Task.Factory.StartNew ( () => {
                ComuniDb.GetIstance().Manutenzione();
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);
            });
        }

        public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
        {    
            LocationManager.GetIstance ().StartLocationUpdates ();
        }
    }
}
```

My app it's not little, I hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Show some code which is in your App.cs and/or AppDelegate

Comment: I add my code. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is logged in the device log, but not in the crash log. It's silly for me (device log has more information than crash log?), but I found the bug and fix it.

Comment: What is the issue? i am also facing the same issue. It will help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Depends on your application. As I said you must check the device log (not the crash log). For me I forgot to check if a file already exist before move another file with the same name in the folder.